# How can I get only one column of Pandas dataframe (without index) and put it into deque?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle, deque

I have a .csv of different companies of form:

| Date (Key) | Company 1 | Company 2 | ... | Company n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | 2 | 11 | ... | 3 |
| 02.01.2020 | 3 | 9 | ... | 45 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 01.11.2021 | 1 | 12 | ... | 34 |

The companies themself I saved in a ticker file. My aim now is to load this stuff of data in a deque of following form:

```
[[Company 1] [2 3 ... 1] [Company 2] [11 0 ... 12] ... [Company n] [3 45 ... 34]]
```

with the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle

from collections import deque

with open("Webscrapper/Sp500tickers.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    tickers = pickle.load(f)

df = pd.read_csv(f"Webscrapper/Sp500tickers_DailyChanges.csv", index_col="Date")

data = [[ticker, df[ticker][0:-1]] for ticker in tickers]
c = deque(data)
print(c)
```

I get the Dates too, means an array of form

```
[[Company 1] [Date Company 1 01.01.2020 2 02.01.2020 2 3 ... 01.11.2021 1] [Company 2] [Date Company 2 01.01.2020 11 02.01.2020 0 ... 01.11.2021 12] ... [Company n] [Date Company n 01.01.2020 3 02.01.2020 45 ... 01.11.2021 34]]
```

How can I convert the array in the desired form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) to convert the columns' values to lists

```
data = [[ticker, df[ticker].tolist()] for ticker in tickers]
c = deque(data)
```